# A functor that “transforms terminal objects in terminal objects”?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, category-theory

In [Lenstra’s notes](https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~hwl/PUBLICATIONS/1985b/GSchemes.pdf) on Galois theory for schmes, he defines a Galois category as a category satisfying a variety of properties (page 33) together with a functor $F$.

One of these properties is that

> “The functor $F$ transforms terminal objects in terminal objects and ... transforms epimorphisms in epimorphisms.”

The usage of the word “in” is throwing me off. Does this just mean that if $A$ is a terminal object in the category $\mathcal{C}$ that the object $F(A)$ is also terminal?

Comment: This looks like a typo where the word "to" was left out. Your guess looks correct to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty certain your guess is right. The terminology is indeed a bit nonstandard (from a category-theoretic point of view). Usually we would say the functor "preserves terminal objects".

The reason I think you are right is because the precise wording in the document is:

> The functor $F$ transforms terminal objects in terminal objects and commutes with
>   fibred products.

Then this statement is equivalent to saying that $F$ preserves all finite limits (the more common category-theoretic term for "fibred products" is "pullbacks"), something that is common to ask of a functor. Such a functor is also called *left exact*, on the [nLab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exact+functor) you can find more on these left exact functors. Including the claim about the equivalence I just mentioned (Proposition 3.2 on that page, at the time of writing).

Comment: This is perfect, thank you!